# Avoid starting test names with "test_" in pytest?

Tags: python, pytest

I want to write descriptive names for my tests, which makes the names long.

Is it possible to avoid having to call a test `test_<something>` and instead use a decorator or something else? Or can this be done via some command line arguments?

Comment: You could shorten it to `t_...` and change the discovery: see e.g. https://pytest.org/latest/example/pythoncollection.html

Comment: Not as pretty, but something to be considered. If you add that as an answer I'll give it an upvote at least.

Comment: There is also: https://pypi.org/project/pytest-relaxed

Answer (score 6, accepted):

You can set it in py.test config, e.g. treat all `check_*.py` as tests files and all functions like `*_spec` as tests:

```
# content of setup.cfg
# can also be defined in in tox.ini or pytest.ini file
[pytest]
python_files=check_*.py
python_functions=*_spec
```

See more at https://pytest.org/latest/example/pythoncollection.html#change-naming-conventions

Comment: Thanks. I was a bit imprecise. I am refering to the test methods, not files. Still, UV, since I was unclear.

Comment: Ahh, perhaps I could set the discovery blob to * and it will work. Gotta run to a meeting, but will test later.

Comment: @TheUnfunCat check the above link, you can customize almost everything included the test methods names

Comment: I meant to replace test with nothing at all, instead of test, not spec or anything else.

Comment: Accepted until sb comes up with a way to use any python function as a test name. Thanks.