# pytest explicitly mark tests

Tags: python, pytest

I'd like to make test names in pytest more readable by avoiding repetition of the word 'test', e.g.:

```
import pytest

def add(a, b):
    return a + b

class TestAdd:
    @pytest.mark('something?')
    def one_and_one_is_two(self):
         assert add(1, 1) == 2
```

Renaming the test to `test_one_and_one_is_two` would be functionally correct, but will result in the name including 'test' twice, which is undesirable.  Is there a mark or other mechanism to explicitly mark the test as a test, and hence avoid the need to rely on the test discovery rules?

I know I can override the default discovery rules, but this means specifying another rule, which wouldn't satisfy all the test names I'll need.

Comment: Does this answer your question? [Avoid starting test names with "test\_" in pytest?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/30161372/avoid-starting-test-names-with-test-in-pytest)

Comment: @HashirIrfan, the question is very similar, but there are no good answers there.  The best answer is to change the discovery rules, but that still doesn't give very readable test names.

Comment: To my knowledge, tests need to be first discovered in order for any marks to take effect. You could discover all possible functions and methods in test directories and then only run tests marked with "test" using `python -m pytest -m test`, but that feels like its going be much trouble for "more readable test names".

Comment: @Tzane Thanks, that makes sense. Sounds like marks are not the way to go.  Is there any other mechanism to influence the discovery process other than test names?

Comment: The 3 main things I know of that affect test discovery are directory structure, file naming and class/method/function naming. You could look into writing your own [collection hooks](https://docs.pytest.org/en/6.2.x/reference.html#collection-hooks). If its only prettier pytest report you are after, maybe you should try to change that instead of messing with test discovery.